# For android development, should I upgrade to Eclipse v4 ?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse v 3.7.2 to develop Android apps. I've been at it a few months and making some decent headway and am not sure I want to rebuild my development environment.

I don't doubt that Eclipse has been improved, but has it been improved for android development?

Before I rebuild my environment I'd like to know why should I fix it.

Can any one tell me if they have found any major feature advantages to upgrading to version 4 of eclipse?

I tried posting in the android enthusiasts group to find the question was "off topic", as there are many developers here I hope ye don't mind a non coding related question.

Comment: I've noticed less crashes and faster "rebuilding work space" but that's about it, not sure of any other benefits off the top of my head.

Comment: I upgraded to Juno shortly, noticed no difference, and went back to Indigo since Juno wouldn't import my settings properly.

Comment: If you use code completion much, I've noticed the popups show quicker with less lag time, so that might be a bonus. Other than that, not much difference I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to rebuild anything. From your 3.7.2 installation you should be able to update your installation to 3.8 in place. Use *Help->Check for updates* with the 3.8 specific update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8

That way you get all the bug fixes and changes of the last release cycle, but do not need to switch to the e4 version of Juno. For you as Eclipse *user* the changes in the modeled workbench and CCS styling are not really important.

Note: Updating in place might be a problem if you use Linux and have installed Eclipse via a repository manager.

Comment: that was better then just a good plan. It was exactly what I needed, I have revisited this 3 times now for different computers and while I will eventually update to v4 for right now its not broken. Many thanks.